# Using Local storage to store and retrieve data to div element

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I am trying to implement Localstorage to my note app. My goal is, when I click on create note icon (".checkIcon") I want to store that note to store and retrieve note from local storage so it will be there when browser refresh.

Here is the JS code, I tried to implement local storage this way, but obviously it doesn't work.

```js
var container2 = document.getElementsByClassName
("container2")[0];

var container3 = document.getElementsByClassName
("container3")[0];

var checkIcon = document.getElementById
("check-icon");

var xIcon = document.getElementById
("x-icon")

var i = 0;

xIcon.addEventListener("click", function(){
    typeNote();
})

checkIcon.addEventListener("click", function(){
    createNote();
})

    function createNote(){
        var noteText = document.getElementById("note-text").value;
        var node0 = document.createElement("div");
        var node1 = document.createElement("h1");

        localStorage.setItem('notes', JSON.stringify(noteText));

        const note = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('notes'));
    
        node1.innerHTML = note;
        
        node1.setAttribute("style", "width:250px; height:250px; font-size:26px; padding:25px;margin-top:10px; overflow:hidden; box-shadow: 0px 10px 24px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75)");
    
        node1.style.margin = margin();
        node1.style.transform = rotate();
        node1.style.background = color();
    
        node0.appendChild(node1);
    
        container2.insertAdjacentElement("beforeend", node0);
    
        node0.addEventListener("mouseenter", function(){
            node0.style.transform = "scale(1.1)";
        })
        node0.addEventListener("mouseleave", function(){
            node0.style.transform = "scale(1)";
        })
        node0.addEventListener("dblclick", function(){
            node0.remove();
        })
        document.getElementById("note-text").value
    }

    function typeNote(){
        if(container3.style.display == "none"){
            container3.style.display = "block";
        }
        else{
            container3.style.display = "none";
        }
    }

function margin(){
var random_margin = ["-5px","1px","5px","10px","15px","20px"];

return random_margin[Math.floor(Math.random() * random_margin.length)];

}

function rotate(){
    var random_rotate = ["rotate(3deg)", "rotate(1deg)","rotate(-1deg)", "rotate(-3deg)","rotate(-5deg)","rotate(-10deg)"];
    
    return random_rotate[Math.floor(Math.random() * random_rotate.length)];

}

function color (){
    var random_color = ["#c2ff3d","#ff3de8","#3dc2ff","#04e022","#bc83e6","#ebb328"];
    
    if(i > random_color.length -1){
        i = 0;
    }
    return random_color[i++]
}
```

Here is the HTML code

```html
<body>
    <div class="container">
    <div class="main-container">
        <div class="container1">
            <button class="btn btn-success" onclick="typeNote()">Create note</button>
        </div>
        <div id="output" class="container2">

        </div>
        <div class="container3">
            <form action="">
                <textarea name="" id="note-text" placeholder="Type Note" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
                <svg id="check-icon" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-check-circle" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                    <path d="M8 15A7 7 0 1 1 8 1a7 7 0 0 1 0 14zm0 1A8 8 0 1 0 8 0a8 8 0 0 0 0 16z"/>
                    <path d="M10.97 4.97a.235.235 0 0 0-.02.022L7.477 9.417 5.384 7.323a.75.75 0 0 0-1.06 1.06L6.97 11.03a.75.75 0 0 0 1.079-.02l3.992-4.99a.75.75 0 0 0-1.071-1.05z"/>
                  </svg>
                  <svg id="x-icon" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-x-circle" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                    <path d="M8 15A7 7 0 1 1 8 1a7 7 0 0 1 0 14zm0 1A8 8 0 1 0 8 0a8 8 0 0 0 0 16z"/>
                    <path d="M4.646 4.646a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0L8 7.293l2.646-2.647a.5.5 0 0 1 .708.708L8.707 8l2.647 2.646a.5.5 0 0 1-.708.708L8 8.707l-2.646 2.647a.5.5 0 0 1-.708-.708L7.293 8 4.646 5.354a.5.5 0 0 1 0-.708z"/>
                  </svg>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently you are setting `notes` on localStorage first and retrieve it directly afterwards. That means you always just retrieve the the value you just set and also that the value of `notes` is overwritten every time a new Note is created.

You probably want to **turn `notes` into an array** to which you append the newly created note (that way you'll have all created notes). And additionally, to display the stored notes in localStorage, a **function that loops through those stored notes** and renders them not only on createNote but on page load.